# Unable to Convert cURL to python requests

Tags: python, curl, python-requests

I'm struggling to convert the below command into a python requests script. The objective is to query this [API](https://dvsa.github.io/mot-history-api-documentation/) for their vehicle MOT history(UK) based on their registration, represented below as `ZZ99ABC`. I've an API key and confirmed via a cURL try that my access is working.

```
curl -H "Accept: application/json+v6" -H "x-api-key: <my_api_key>" \https://beta.check-mot.service.gov.uk/trade/vehicles/mot-tests\?registration=ZZ99ABC
```

So far my attempt is producing a 403 response, missing an authentication token.

```
import requests
import json

reg = "ZZ99ABC"
url = f"https://beta.check-mot.service.gov.uk/trade/vehicles/mot-tests"
payload = {'registration': reg}
headers = {'x-api-key': '<my_api_key>',
            'Accept': 'application/json+v6'}

r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)
```

Any ideas where I potentially got this wrong?

Thank you in advance

`requests.__version__ == '2.26.0'`
`python --version == 3.9.2`

Comment: You need to use GET method: `requests.get`

Answer (score 0):

For any novice requests users like myself. Following @Florian C. advice and using the `PreparedRequest` Class solved my query.

```
import requests
from requests.models import PreparedRequest

url = r"https://beta.check-mot.service.gov.uk/trade/vehicles/mot-tests"
params= {'registration': '<your_reg>'}
req = PreparedRequest()
req.prepare_url(url, params)
headers = {'x-api-key': '<your_api_key>',
            'Accept': 'application/json+v6'}

r = requests.get(req.url, headers=headers)
```

Answer (score 0):

this suppose to work:

```
import requests

headers = {
    'Accept': 'application/json+v6',
    'x-api-key': '<my_api_key>',
}

params = (
    ('registration', 'ZZ99ABC'),
)

response = requests.get('/https://beta.check-mot.service.gov.uk/trade/vehicles/mot-tests/', headers=headers, params=params)
```